# How to get number of threads inside docker image

Tags: java, dockerfile, pthreads

I am using maven docker image (https://github.com/carlossg/docker-maven/blob/bdffb5117c33476d554325d8efe5866306004b99/openjdk-15/Dockerfile) specifically maven:3.6.3-openjdk-15. I have been getting an 'Failed to start thread - pthread_create failed (EAGAIN) for attributes: stacksize: 1024k, guardsize: 0k, detached.' error so I suspect the number of threads has something to do with this. In my docker file I have:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar", "-Xmx600m","/app.jar"]
```

I want to 1) get the number of max threads allowed 2) increase the number of max threads allowed threads and 3) be able to figure out the number of threads currently running. I tried running ps but it does not recognize that command. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You want to achieve this using java? Or does `docker container top` help? See [doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_top/)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use `docker container stats` and look at the PIDs column.